# Replace file blob in browser?

Tags: javascript, file, blob

I asked this earlier but someone down voted and accused me of trying to write files to local filesystem without reading.

I have website in an enterprise environment which will only ever be accessed in chrome so keep that in mind.

I am able to select a local folder on my PC and open all sub-folders and files in the browser. I'm using client side javascript to parse these files and look for a particular kind of .xml file that is used internally to render a powerpoint like presentation. I can make changes to this xml file and spit it back out as a blob.

What I would like to do but don't know how is replace the data or blob in the original file with the modified data/blob.

Answer (score 2):

Can the user interact with the data blob? If so, you can use a save file function and overwrite the original.

```
function saveFile( data )
{
  var textFileAsBlob = new Blob([yourData], {type:'text/plain'});
  //or replace the code above with your already formed blob

  var fileNameToSaveAs = "File_Name_Goes_Here.xml";

  var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
  downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
  //downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";
  if (window.webkitURL != null){
      // Chrome allows the link to be clicked
      // without actually adding it to the DOM.
      downloadLink.href = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
  }
  else{
      // Firefox requires the link to be added to the DOM
      // before it can be clicked.
      try {
          downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
          downloadLink.onclick = destroyClickedElement;
          downloadLink.style.display = "none";
          document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
      }
      catch( e ){
          console.log("error saving firefox file")
      }
      // IE 10+
      try {
          window.navigator.msSaveBlob(textFileAsBlob, fileNameToSaveAs);
      }
      catch(e){
          console.log("error saving IE file")
      }
  }

  try {
      downloadLink.click();
  }
  catch(e) {
      console.log("Unable to click the download link.  Are you using IE?")
  }

}
```

I grabbed this code from somewhere else on stack overflow. I can't remember who it's from though to provide attribution :-(

Comment: I know you said it was a chrome only problem, but I figured I would add the other other browser support in for other people who may stumble across this. If you don't need them, just remove the if/try/catch blocks.

Comment: Just from reading the above code, this works if the intent was to re-download just the modified file. I need to pick a directory full of xml's, change each one, then what I'll do is zip ALL files and offer the zip as a download link.  So basically I'll have an array of xml's after picking a folder. I'll iterate over each file and read it's data into a variable, make my changes, but I need to apply those changes to the original file in the array.

Comment: why would you need to offer a zip of files to download it you are changing the files on place?

Comment: I'm not sure how this relates to my question.

Comment: Can you re-frame or re-ask the question? It seems most people have interpreted what you're attempting to do differently than you anticipated.